# make the focus on a particular div after button click

Tags: javascript

I am having a form in a page for registering various entertainment programs on a particular stage. After submitting all the details and clicking on submit button, it should check whether a program exists on that stage on the particular day. If any program exists, a div should show the existing program with the full details.My issue is that if any program exists, i need to make the focus on that newly generated div (I mean that div should be visible,no editing is required). I need it because, div is generated with the help of AJAX and the form is so lengthy, so user cannot see the div generated, unless he/she scrolls upward.
NB:The div is created in the top position.
Is there any way to make the div portion to be visible after form submitting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the following statement works for me.

```
document.getElementById('id').scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: it gives me error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoview' of null

Comment: This lacks support from most browsers:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: It will be "scrollIntoView" and not "scrollIntoview" (please see the capital "V").

Answer (score 19):

Regularly, you can not focus a div. But if you will add a tabindex to it, it will work:

```
<div tabindex="0">test </div>
```

Here is a demo:

```css
.z{margin-top:800px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="$('.z')[0].focus()" value="test" />
<div>
    <div class="z" tabindex="0">test </div>
</div>
```

If you click on test button div should became focused and jump into view.
On click I just do something like `divElement.focus()`

Another option is just to scroll area which contains your newly added div, like in other answers here.

Comment: I've been searching for a solution to this for a few now, this works perfectly, thank you much!

Answer (score 10):

You can use code like this to jump to the div

```
$(window).scrollTop($('#new_div').offset().top-20)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can scroll to the top of the page with :

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

or with jQuery using :

```
$('html,body').scrollTop(0);
```

Or with some fun effect

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="button" onclick="$('#c')[0].focus()" value="test focus" />
<div>
    <div id="c" tabindex="1" style="margin-top:800px;">testing</div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/N7TU4/)

Comment: Most likely down-voted because its lacking explanation and using jQuery inline. I would say this is all just bad practice all around. jQuery was also not mentioned as a need here. Need to be careful when answering JS questions by assuming they are using your libraries, unless they actually say it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `window.scrollTop = #VALUE;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var selector = document.getElementById('YOUR_ID_SELECTOR');

if(typeof selector.scrollIntoView !== 'undefined' )
    selector.scrollIntoView();
```

The basic version of the method "scrollIntoView" supports IE8+.

Here is the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView